# angularjs issue with my routing where multiple views are there

Tags: angularjs

I was following `angular-phonecat` tutorial and trying to build something in the same way.

In my `index.html` file I am having list of venue and their images, when I select a particular venue i need to shift to another view with the details about it. However, I am getting the same output as their in my view html file (like this. **detail view for {{venueId}}**, where the venueid is not resolving and display as venueid only)

### index.html

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="venue in venues | filter: venue | orderBy: predicate" class="thumbnail">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#/venue-details/{{venue.id}}"><img ng-src="{{venue.imageUrl}}"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#/venue-details/{{venue.id}}" class="thumb"> {{ venue.name }}</a>  
      </div>
  </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

### config.router.js

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {}])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', 
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('search', {
          url: '/search',
          templateUrl: 'templates/search2.html'
        })
        .state('/venue-details/:venueId', {
          url: '/venue-details',
          templateUrl: 'templates/venue-details.html',
          controller: 'venueDetailCtrl'
        });
      }
  ]);
```

### controller.js

```
app.controller('venueDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateProvider',
  function($scope, $stateProvider) {
    $scope.venueId = $stateProvider.venueId;
  }
]);
```

### venue-details.html

```
detail view for <span>{{venueId}}</span>
```

Comment: any time the raw expressions `{{ }}` print on the final output, it's an indication that you have some sort of script error that caused angular to not process the page.  What error(s) are in the browser console log?  Those are going to be what helps solve this problem.

Comment: i am not getting any errors, i am getting the view for venues but venueid is not resolving. my output in the venue view is  "detail view for venueid"

Comment: so are you now saying that you *aren't* seeing the `{{ }}` in the output, but the string literal `venueid`?

Comment: yes. i dont know where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function($scope, $stateProvider) {
        $scope.venueId = $stateProvider.venueId;
      }]);
```

Not $stateProvider : $stateParams :)

this might be problematic

```
.state('/venue-details/:venueId', {
                            url: '/venue-details',
                            templateUrl: 'templates/venue-details.html',
                            controller: 'venueDetailCtrl'
                      })
```

it should be like

```
.state('venuedetail', {
      url: '/venue-details/:venueId',
      templateUrl: 'templates/venue-details.html',
      controller: 'venueDetailCtrl'
})
```

There is problem in state name i think

Comment: @krish : thanks, i didn't see that the state wasn't properly defined too.

Comment: sorry guys still i am having the problem. here's my output:" detail view for {{venueId}}",   after changing the stateProvider to stateparams in my controller i am getting an error now as injector unknown provider "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $statePramasProvider <- $statePramas <- venueDetailCtrl"

Comment: read well : $state***Pramas***Provider <- $state***Pramas*** you have a typo :)

Comment: oops sorry.such a silly mistake :/. uff i might be disgusting , now my output is ** detail view for   **. venueid is still not resolved

Comment: did you fix the state declaration as krish edit my post ? If it doesn't work change href by ui-sref=venuedetail({venueId:venue.id}) And just in case : print your venue.id in your main view.

Comment: yeah i  changed it. app.controller('venueDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
  function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.venueId = $stateParams.venueId;
  }]);   .  still its not working for me .same output i am having **detail view for  **

Comment: Hum can you edit your post and add the state of your current code please ? And did you add the ui-sref directive which is the directive that you should use over href="" in order to navigate from state to state.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow really helps beginners like me. Thanks alot guys for your help.Got it fixed.There was an error with my id declarations. I was using id somewhere and Id somewhere so i think it created an issue. Actually i tried it with another bindings in venues like venue.details etc. everything was working, but not with Id , then i figured it out. Thanks for the help guys for fixing my state params declaration error. here's full working code

**index.html**

```
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                     <a href="#/search/{{venue.id}}"><img ng-src="{{venue.imageUrl}}"></a></div>
                     <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <a ui-sref="venuedetail({venueid:venue.id})" class="thumb"> {{ venue.name }}</a>  
                     </div>
```

**config.router.js**

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {}])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', 
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('search', {
          url: '/search',
          templateUrl: 'templates/search2.html'
        })
        .state('/venue-details/:venueid', {
          url: '/venue-details',
          templateUrl: 'templates/venue-details.html',
          controller: 'venueDetailCtrl'
        });
      }
  ]);
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('venueDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateProvider',
  function($scope, $stateProvider) {
    $scope.venueid = $stateProvider.venueid;
  }
]);
```

**venue-details.html**

```
detail view for <span>{{venueId}}</span>
```